# best way to retrieve data using multiple parameters in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have created a table that contains the userid, the content that they posted on their newsfeed, the date of when they posted it, and a primary key(I am using nodejs)

my first shot at retrieving the data was me trying use an `IN` clause and passing an array as a paramater.

```
"SELECT * FROM SomeKeySpace WHERE userId IN (?) ALLOW FILTERING"
```

But then after some research I realized that `IN` clauses should be avoided especially when passing alot of parameters.

This is what my table looks. Id is the primary key

```
 id      | date        | content             | userid
---------+-------------+-------------------------+--------
 1427181 | 27-Apr-2018 |           sometext  |   5332
```

I am trying to retrieve the date and the content filtered by userids. In the attempt that i mentioned above I had retrieved all the userIds from another db and pushed them to an array then i passed it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what other queries you're planning to execute - in Cassandra you need to model data around your queries.

For your specific question, you need either secondary index on `userid`, and do search (there are also some limitations there), or build second table with composite primary key consisting of `userid, date, id` - this would be especially useful if you'll have query "Show me all blog posts by this user".

Doing `ALLOW FILTERING` is generally is not recommended, because it may cause scanning of your whole cluster.